# Mono Tools for Visual Studio in vc++ express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mono, mono-tools

Will the $99 Mono Tools for Visual Studio http://www.go-mono.com/store/ work in express editions of visual studio (has anyone achieved this)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The Express edition of Visual Studio does not support plugins.